# Letuce redis brpop command

Tags: redis

```
        redisListCommands.brpop(0, queueName)
```

**I have set timeout 0 (i.e. without timeout). And why this**
**command brings**
 io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandTimeoutException: Command timed out
    at io.lettuce.core.LettuceFutures.awaitOrCancel(LettuceFutures.java:114)
    at io.lettuce.core.FutureSyncInvocationHandler.handleInvocation(FutureSyncInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at io.lettuce.core.internal.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.brpop(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you ask that again? There is a Redis server timeout and your client (lettuce) connection timeout. When you build a connection, use `withTimeout` with very high value. Unfortunately, you can't set 0 here.

```
RedisURI.builder().withHost(...).withPort(...)
    .withTimeout(Duration.ofDays(10000)).build();
```

Comment: sorry dear @lmaskar,I didtn see your comment. Thank you for help. So, on brpop first parameter is Redis server timeout ,and your above mentioned timeout is Lotuce connection timeout?

In my case I should put both timeouts first by 0,and for connection for example 10000 days.? Isnt it?

Comment: That's right. I think an issue should be filled to lettuce to allow `0` as `no timeout`.